# 2020 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

The 2020 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure if I'm alone in this (a boycott by one person isn't very noticeable after all) or whether it will prove to be a common theme; but I will not be voting in any of the community moderator elections this year.

Neither will I complete the developer survey this year.

This is because I don't feel that I should reward Stack Exchange's recent firing of Monica by helping them ignore the situation and sweep it under the carpet.

Comment: I support you..